# Proof of complex integrals involving trigonometic functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I came across a way of solving the following integrals:
$$I_1=\int\cos\left[\ln x\right]dx$$
$$I_2=\int\sin\left[\ln x\right]dx$$
firstly:
$$\int x^idx=\frac{x^{i+1}}{i+1}+C \tag{1}$$
and we also know that:
$$\int x^idx=\int e^{i\ln(x)}dx=\int\cos\left[\ln x\right]+i\sin\left[\ln x\right]dx\tag{2}$$
Rearranging $(1)$ we get:
$$\frac{x^{1+i}}{1+i}=\frac{1-i}{2}x^{1+i}=\frac{x}{2}\left(\cos\left[\ln x\right]+i\sin\left[\ln x\right]-i\cos\left[\ln x\right]+\sin\left[\ln x\right]\right)$$
$$=\frac{x\left(\cos\left[\ln x\right]+\sin\left[\ln x\right]\right)}{2}+i\frac{x\left(\sin\left[\ln x\right]-\cos\left[\ln x\right]\right)}{2}\tag{3}$$
and so when we combine $(2)$ and $(3)$ we get:
$$\int\cos\left[\ln x\right]dx=\frac{x\left(\cos\left[\ln x\right]+\sin\left[\ln x\right]\right)}{2}+C$$
$$\int\sin\left[\ln x\right]dx=\frac{x\left(\sin\left[\ln x\right]-\cos\left[\ln x\right]\right)}{2}+C$$
Is this correct? And does anyone have any similar examples of where this method can be used?

Comment: You can check yourself whether attempted anti-derivatives are correct.  Differentiate the right-hand-side, and see if the result is the integrand.

Comment: Yes when differentiated it gives the desired result, but are there any limitation that I have overlooked, other than the function not being continuous for real

Comment: Your integrand must have $x>0$.  Then $x^i$ is defined and has the continuous principal value you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall 
$$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\sin \log x=&\frac{e^{i\log x}-e^{-i\log x}}{2i}\\
=&\frac{x^{i}-x^{-i}}{2i}\\
\end{align}$$
Similarly:
$$\cos \log x=\frac{x^i+x^{-i}}2$$
each of which can be easily integrated giving the desired results.